# Running private PostgreSQL instance in a shared host

Tags: postgresql, shared-hosting

I installed a private PostgreSQL in a shared host account, created the database cluster and started the server without a problem. However, the server stops as soon as I log out. Why does this happen and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 2):

The server stops probably because you started it with the a command from the commandline. It runs in your ssh instance and if you logout the server stops.

You might use so program named `screen`. Simply start it with the command `screen`. It will allow you to have many terminals open, even if you logout.

After you entered `screen` start your database server. To quit the console press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the server is still running and it's save to disconnect the ssh instance.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is the prefix for commands and <kbd>D</kbd> stands for detach.

This way you can create multiple "consoles", that stay open. See `man screen` for further information.

If you reconnect to the server you can run `screen -r` to connect again to the running shell.

Comment: This is a shared host, can't do that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't thought about the problems you have on a shared host. I will correct my answer :)

Comment: @mgois did this solve your problem? If it does, consider accepting this answer ;)

Comment: No, some other issues appeared and since time was short, ended up running PostgresSQL inside a docker container which has in the meanwhile become one of my favorite tools :)

Comment: @mgois Docker is a great solution too :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `nohup` command: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: Didn't work, the server still gets killed. Could it be due to the shell being jailshell?